# Can network traffic analyzer see the call to a DNS server?

Tags: dns

I have a network traffic analyzer installed on my machine that sees all the incoming and outgoing traffic. It shows all the TCP UDP and all the other connections, that causes traffic in and out of my machine. When I try to access a website, am I not supposed to see a call to a DNS server that resolves the website? I am not able to see that. How can I see that call? What port number is used for a DNS service call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's UDP (and sometimes TCP) port 53.

If you already visited this website recently, DNS may be cached on your machine, and thus there will be no DNS request.

Comment: is there a way to delete the DNS cache?

Comment: @developer747 I assume yes. My telepathy isn't developed enough to know which OS you are using though. Or you may query some new domain name to see the requests.